# pandas apply function throwing value error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Not sure what I have done wrong.

I have a Pandas Dataframe and run an apply function on it.

here is the function below.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor_new2.py", line 79, in <module>
    df['status'] = df.apply(status, axis=1)
  File "/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4360, in apply
    ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
  File "/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4456, in _apply_standard
    results[i] = func(v)
  File "monitor_new2.py", line 44, in status
    if df['was_it_big'] == 'YES' and df['should_it_have_run'] == 'YES' and df['did_it_run_today'] == 'YES':
  File "/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 953, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0')
```

function:

```
def status(row):
    if str(df['was_it_big']) == 'YES' and str(df['should_it_have_run']) == 'YES' and str(df['did_it_run_today']) == 'YES':
        status = 'Pass'
    elif str(df['should_it_have_run']) == 'NO' and str(df['did_it_run_today']) == 'NO':
        status = 'Pass'
    elif str(df['should_it_have_run']) == 'NO' and str(df['did_it_run_today']) == 'YES':
        status = 'Pass'
    else:
        status = 'Fail'
    return status
```

Comment: I don't think this is your issue, but I think you want to swap out `str(df['...']) ==...` for `str(row['...']) ==...`

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe and the command how to applied a function on df.

Comment: Thanks @Andy that works well. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Thanks @kikee1222, I've added the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping out `str(df['...']) ==...` for `str(row['...']) ==...`

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate it